# Glyphicons com erro ao publicar no IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-glyphicons

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com [asp.net-mvc-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5) e [Bootsrap 3.3.5](http://getbootstrap.com). No visual studio, funciona perfeitamente. Porém, ao publicar a plicação no IIS 8, os [bootstrap-glyphicons](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-glyphicons) aparecem com um sinal de "**?**".

Pesquisando um pouco, li que poderia ser problemas com os arquivos de fontes, então realizei o download diretamente do site e substitui. Porém, sem sucesso.

Em outros casos, eram que o arquivo não era localizado e não era feito o download, porém, ao debugar pelo Chrome, verifico que está realizando o download normalmente, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em outros casos, li sobre o **MIME Type** no **IIS**. Neste caso, tentei adicionar esse código em meu **Web.Config**:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/truetype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

E no **IIS** está configurado desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, de qualquer forma, na aplicação continua à mostrar o sinal de "**?**", como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SubirSequenciaCorrecao", new { id = item.Sequencia })" title="Subir" id="submitbtn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" />
</a>
```

Ao executar a aplicação no Visual Studio, publicada no **Local IIS**, ela funciona normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Edição

Analisando os Sources no console, vi que possui diferença nos arquivos que o Browser "acha".

Na aplicação rodando no IIS, são esses:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rodando no Visual Studio, são esses:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notei que se retirar o `bootstrap.css` do **BundlesConfig**, os ícones aparecem normalmente. Meu **BundlesConfig** está da seguinte forma:

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/application.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dataTables").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/dataTable").Include(
                       "~/Content/dataTable/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
                        "~/Content/dataTable/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"
                    ));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ao inspecionar o elemento com a interrogação, o que o inspetor do browser informa na folha de estilo da classe `glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Na aplicação rodando no IIS aparece: `content: "?"`. Na aplicação rodando pelo Visual Studio aprarece: `content: "\e094"`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez notei que é algo referente ao bundles. Editei a pergunta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente é problema no transformador de *Bundling*. Experimente usar outro *Bundle Transformer*, [como o Yui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Yui), e veja o que acontece.

Exemplo de uso:

```
var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css");
cssBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssTransformer(new YuiCssMinifier()));
bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

Comment: Funcionou normalmente. Teria algum problema utilizar os dois Bundle's, ou tenho que adaptar todos ao Yui?

Comment: Não, pode usar normalmente os outros *engines*.

Comment: Obrigado mais um vez.

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema.

Para não utilizar uma nova engine ([conforme @CiganoMorrisonMendez citou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74006/30792)) a solução se deu em setar corretamente o *responseEncoding* e *requestEncoding* da aplicação.

Antes eu utilizava:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="Windows-1252" 
                   responseEncoding="Windows-1252" 
                   responseHeaderEncoding="Windows-1252" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Alterando para UTF-8, os Glyphicons funcionaram normalmente:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" 
                   responseEncoding="utf-8" 
                   responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Se você não possui a tag *globalization* configurada no *web.config* da sua aplicação, provavelmente está configurado diretamente no IIS, em: *SeuServer > .Net Globalization > Encoding*.